# issue with ajax post in laravel

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel-7

I am making one state module for which I want to make create state popup

and for that I have make below code

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#save_state_detail', function() {
        
    var url_variable = '{{ route("admin.state.store") }}';
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url_variable,
            async: false, 
            data: $('#state_form_add').serialize(),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                if(data.status === 422)
                {
                    $('.error').html('');
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    $.each( errors.errors, function( key, value ) {
                        $('#error_'+key).html(value);   
                    });
                }
            },
        });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbspNew State
    </button>  
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add State</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            
            @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
            
            <form role="form" action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" id="state_form_add">
            @csrf
            <div class="box-body">
                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">State Name <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="State Name" name="name" value="{{ old('name')}}">
            </div>
            
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="save_state_detail" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.','middleware' => ['auth']],function(){
    Route::resources([
       'state' => 'Admin\StateController',
    ]);
});
```

and make controller

```
public function store(StateRequest $request)
{
    $create = new StateModel();
    $result = $create::create([
        'name' => $input['name']
    ]);
    if($result){
        $data_info = [
            'msg' => 'Success',
            'error' => 0
        ];
    }else{
        $data_info = [
            'msg' => 'Something wend wrong',
            'error' => 1
        ];
    }
    return response()->json($data_info);
}
```

and add rules in request file

```
public function rules()
{
    app()->getLocale();
    return [
        'name' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

with above code if I fill data in input box it is correctly inserted in database but if I submit form with blank input it is showing me error `422 Unprocessable Entity Explained`

can anybody help me with this my request file's path is correct but issue with validation response

Comment: Are you sure that `data: $('#state_form_add').serialize()` actually works? I've never seen this jquery style of filling up data to post. If this works, fine. A 422 is a synonym for 400, bad request. You try to force something the server can only partially understand, but can't complete. Because the syntax is malformed. By the way, it should be `contentType = 'json',` not what you've put. If it is json anyway, you can drop the content type all together. jQuery expects json by default. And so does the Laravel framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#state_form_add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let name = $('#exampleInputEmail1').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route("admin.state.store") }}',
            data: { name },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
});
```

And the opening of your form should be `<form id="state_form_add">`. Nothing more is needed. Apart from missing bootstrap classes. But that has nothing to do with your 422 error. Keep the ajax setup header. Of course.

Comment: I have tried your code as well but it is also not working and give me `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Comment: Do you use xampp or simimar? If my proposed code doesn't work, it seems your testserver is wrongly configured. What do you see if you run in your `store()` method `dd($request);` and/or `dd(request()->all());`? Do you find your posted data there?